# Display value from edittext in textview

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make EditText programmatically inside a loop.

What I'm currently doing:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int quan = 0;
    LinearLayout linear;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        for (int  i =0; i < quan; i++)
        {
            EditText myEditText = new EditText(this);
            myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            linear.addView(myEditText);
        }
    }
}
```

but I want to store the value from all EditTexts and display them in some TextView
how I can get values from all EditTexts?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve text from your EditTexts when some event happens (e.g. button click) or dynamically when the user starts to input inside them?

Comment: When some event happens like when the user input all information and click on Done button, all information display in textview from all edittext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two easy steps to achieve this:

1. Add your `EditText`s to some kind of List when creating them.
2. Read values inside a `foreach` when some event (e.g. button click) happens.

I used StringBuilder to reduce the number of Strings created in heap String Pool.

```
// 1 - Add all of your EditTexts inside some ArrayList as a member of class
private ArrayList mEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

// 2 - Add your EditTexts to @mEditTexts when you are creating them
...
...
mEditTexts.add(editText);

// 3 - In your event handler, when you need to get all values
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
for(EditText editText : mEditTexts) {
  String content = editText.getText().toString().trim();
  stringBuilder.append(content);
}

textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)`  on your `EditText`, the watcher will receive `onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)` on every change, and you can use the sequence to update your `TextView`.
More information here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher